# Symfony 3 with multiple entity managers and translations with KnpLabs

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, translation

I have a problem in my project, I'm using KnpLabs DoctrineBehavior for entity translations and I need to connect two Entity managers, when i add the translation to the not default entity manager i'm getting a mapping error:

> The class 'NodoBundle\Entity\Club' was not found in the chain
>   configured namespaces BackendBundle\Entity, UserBundle\Entity,
>   FOS\UserBundle\Model 500 Internal Server Error - MappingException

This is my entity manager configuration

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
        default:
            driver:   pdo_mysql
            host:     "%database_host%"
            port:     "%database_port%"
            dbname:   "%database_name%"
            user:     "%database_user%"
            password: "%database_password%"
            charset:  UTF8
            mapping_types:
                enum: string
        nodo:
            driver:   pdo_mysql
            host:     "%database_host2%"
            port:     "%database_port2%"
            dbname:   "xxxx"
            user:     "%database_user%"
            password: "%database_password%"
            charset:  UTF8
  orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            auto_mapping: true
            mappings:
                BackendBundle: ~
                FrontendBundle: ~
                UserBundle: ~
                FOSUserBundle: ~
        nodo:
            connection: nodo
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            mappings: 
                NodoBundle: ~
                DoctrineBehaviorsBundle: ~
```

I'm trying different mapping configurations but none has worked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe (if im not mistaking without checking the code), that the choice of entitymanager is set as the 'connection' parameter on the TranslatableListener (in config), so you would need to change this to the appropriate connection.

Comment: I don't have any translatable listener. I only enabled the translatable parameter in KNP_DOCTRINE_BEHAVIORS to true. The oficial document of Knplabs don´t say anything about translatable listener.
`knp_doctrine_behaviors:
    translatable: true
    timestampable: true
    sluggable: true`